# How to input List of Types into Generic Class<T>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have generic class looks like this:

```
public interface IFoo<T> where T : class
{
    IList<T> GetFoo();
}

public class Foo<T> : IFoo<T> where T : class
{
    public IList<T> GetFoo()
    {
       //return something in here
    }
}
```

And I want to use that class from the collection of types from assembly like this:

```
public class Bar
{
    public IList<string> GetTheFoo()
    {
        IList<Type> theClass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsClass).ToList();

        var theList = new List<string>();
        foreach (Type theType in theClass)
        {
            //not working...
            theList.Add(new Foo<theType>().GetFoo() );
        }
    }
}
```

But the compiler cannot accept the type from the list.
How to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Type.MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) to create the type you want dynamically:

```
 var item = typeof(Foo<>).MakeGenericType(theType);
```

Since these items would be all different you would only be able to store them in a `List<object>` though.

Comment: Hi, it's not working, I tried do like this: new Foo<item>().GetFoo() still no luck.

Comment: You cannot put the runtime type instance between **<** and **>**,  until you use the way suggested by BrokenGlass. And, as he wrote, you are to put the result into a list of objects, not a list of strings, because each implementation returns list of different things. Oh, and it should be AddRange, not Add.